# Find the radius of convergence of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I used Dalamber's criteria, but when I solve the limit I find that it goes to infinity, which looks wrong. I think I might have done something wrong while simplifying the expression, but I don't quite know how to work with expression that contain factorials.

I would appreciate your help!

$$\sum_{n=1}^n \ \frac{(n!)^2x^n}{(2n)!} $$

Comment: Use $R=1/ \limsup |a_{n+1}/a_n|$. It should go smoothly.

Comment: @luka5z The problem is that I do not know how to work with factorials and can not solve the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient you have to use is (for $x\ne0$)
$$
\left|
\frac{\dfrac{((n+1)!)^2x^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}}{\dfrac{(n!)^2x^n}{(2n)!}}
\right|
=
\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}\right|\frac{((n+1)!)^2}{(n!)^2}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}=
|x|\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}
$$
and its limit as $n\to\infty$ is $|x|/4$. This is less than $1$ if and only if $|x|<4$ (and $x\ne0$). So the radius of convergence is $4$.

Just note that
$$
\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=n+1,
\qquad
\frac{(2n+2)!}{(2n)!}=(2n+2)(2n+1)
$$

Comment: Can you please show how you simplify the limit because i do not get the answer that you have shown.

Comment: @Al.Ka I added the tricks I used

Answer (score 0):

Call $a_n$ the coefficient of your power series (ie $a_n = \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$)

Use Stirling approximation of the factorial to compute $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, and then use the fact that $$R = 1 / \limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$ (Cauchy Hadamard theorem)

Comment: Is there any easier way please? Because  Stirling approximation is not mentioned in my book.

Comment: @Al.Ka Stirling approximation is probably the easier way, just put $n! \sim \left(\frac ne\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$ and you're done. If you want to use another method.. I'll think about it :)